# Delphi XE7 Isapi.dll Azure

Tags: delphi, iis, azure, delphi-xe7

I posted this earlier on forums.embarcadero.com, but I have not got an example of how to setup.

Anyone out here have experience setting up a ISAPI.dll app to run on Azure?

I would like to have a "hello world" dll setup instruction for Azure.

Today I am using Webbroker and datasnap servers hosted on ec2 servers on Amazon and RDS MYSQL, but I would love to use IIS as a service on Azure, not a instance.
I am looking for a todo description howto setup and run a ISAPI developed in Delphi on IIS as a service on Azure.

What tools do I need to Install and so on.

I have tried to read myself up on Azure, but I am not able to figure out how to deploy my ISAPI, or where to start.

If you have any website or places where I can find more information I am very thankful.

Comment: Have you tried something along these lines? https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/29cdf931-4a86-4fa0-b2ae-c3081e8559c0/how-to-implement-an-isapi-extension-in-azure

Comment: Thanks , but I have not tried it. Don't now what SDK to download or where to start.  is it .NET  do I need Visual Studio ?

Comment: I think it is just some text files you edit to configure an ISAPI as a service on Azure.

Comment: I guess I still needs some tool to download / upload those txt files